# sort values in a dict (low to high)

Tags: python

I want to sort my dict values by the lowest number to the highest, my function is working like this, looping through a directory, checking if the path is a file, if yes, updating the dict with the file's name and with the file's size as the values.

I want to sort the dict values from the lowest number to the highest

**Code:**

```
def get_files_size(self):
        user_files_size = {}
        for files in os.listdir(self.folder):
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.folder, files)):
                user_files_size.update({files: os.path.getsize(os.path.join(self.folder, files))})
        return user_files_size
```

Current Output:

```
{'test1.txt': 13, 'test2.txt': 0}
```

Excepted output:

```
{'test1.txt': 0, 'test2.txt': 13}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: @FarhoodET Hey, I have already saw it and it didn't helped me.

Comment: I don't understand. What is different between what the other question explains, and what you want to know/do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you by sorting on values.

```
import operator
user_files_size  = sorted(user_files_size.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

if you want to sort on key then use this

```
import operator
user_files_size  = sorted(user_files_size.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```